# GPUImageView disappears on Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, gpuimage

I've been working on a live video app with GPUImage.

I have a storyboard, where I have set the class of my View to be `GPUImageView`.

In my ViewController.m file, in my ViewDidLoad(), I am making a main view as such:

```
CGRect mainScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIView *primaryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainScreenFrame];
self.view = primaryView;
```

Then I am making three subviews

```
highlightView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, mainScreenFrame.size.width, mainScreenFrame.size.height)];
shadowView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, mainScreenFrame.size.width, mainScreenFrame.size.height)];
midView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, mainScreenFrame.size.width, mainScreenFrame.size.height)];
```

Then I add them to the main view

```
[self.view addSubview:midView];
[self.view addSubview:shadowView];
[self.view addSubview:highlightView];
```

There's a bunch of filter chaining, loading images, etc in there too, but I think this is the relevant part...

Anyways, the behaviour I am experiencing is that the View flashes onscreen once for a frame, right around when the end of the method call happens, then goes black... and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

I had all the code working with a .xib file earlier, but for various reasons I need to be working on a Storyboard for this project... any hints appreciated!

Comment: That sounds like an input is being prematurely deallocated. Is your video camera an instance variable of your controller class, so that it's held on to past the setup method? Do you have any picture instances that you're blending in that might need to be held on to?

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks for the comment. I had to step away from this project briefly, but will take a look at this in the morning. Should the camera be an instance variable? Will that retain it properly ?

Comment: @BradLarson Hmm.. Yes, the camera is declared in my header and then allocated/used in my controller, if that's what you mean. And I'm using an ARC-based project, so i can't retain it. I'll take a look at the pictures Im using...